# Is there a way to infinitely loop through Map elements in java?

Tags: java, dictionary

Suppose I have a Map with `m` elements in it, like the following.

```
Map<String,Integer> mp = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

mp.put("Delhi",1);
mp.put("Bombay",1);
mp.put("Bangalore",1);
```

Here, `m = 3`. I would like to access the map of above elements in a cyclic order for specific number of times `n`, where `n` != `m`. Each time I access the `Map` I want to get the "next" element in the `Map` (so that implies that the `Map` entries are somehow ordered). If I get to the end of the `Map` I want to start over again at the beginning, since I want in all cases to access the map exactly `n` times. There is no relationship between `n` and `m`. Each time I access a map element I want to increase the value of that element by 1.

For example, given the above `Map` with 3 elements (`m == 3`), and supposing I want to access the `Map` five times in total (`n == 5`). The following should happen:

step-->String(Key)-->Integer(Value)

> 1-->Delhi-->2
>
> 2-->Bombay-->2
>
> 3-->Bangalore-->2
>
> 4-->Delhi-->3
>
> 5-->Bombay-->3

Any suggestions on this would be appreciated, even change of DataStructure as well.

I am specifically looking to loop through the map elements in tandem with an external loop.

What I don't want: suppose I have a for loop say

```
for(1 to numberofcycles)
{
    for(iterate-->mapelements)
    {
        //looping mapelements
    }
}
```

I would be looping through the map `numberofcycles` * `numberofmap` elements which is not what i am expecting to achieve.

Instead, I would like to achieve to loop through `mapelements` for exactly `numberofcycles` in cyclic order and changing/adding 1 to value after each visit.

i.e.

keep iterating through map in cyclic order until specific condition is reached.

Comment: Just do it? Since you want to iterate over all elements anyways then order shouldn't be a matter (and if you don't change the map then subsequent calls to `values()` should return the same order). If order matters then use a `LinkedHashMap` instead.

Comment: You can possibly achive this by writing a program. If you encounter any problems in doing so you could write a question at SO.

Comment: Googling your question could be a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to make a total of `n` trips, each one to a different destination, and you're visiting those destinations in a predefined order. How about something like this...

## If you want to specify the order independent of the Map

```
Map<String,Integer> mp = new HashMap<>();

mp.put("Delhi",1);
mp.put("Bombay",1);
mp.put("Bangalore",1);

int numberOfTrips = 5;
List<String> orderOfVisits = Arrays.asList("Delhi", "Bombay", "Bangalore");
Iterator<String> visiterator = orderOfVisits.iterator();

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTrips; i++) {
  // Get a new iterator if we've exhausted the previous one
  if (!visiterator.hasNext()) {
    visiterator = orderOfVisits.iterator();
  }

  // Get the correct city and increment the counter
  String key = visiterator.next();
  mp.put(key, mp.get(key) + 1);
}

// demonstrate that the map contains the correct values
for (Entry<String, Integer> entry: mp.entrySet()) {
  System.out.println("Key:" + entry.getKey() + ", Value:" + entry.getValue());
}
```

## If you want the Map to govern the order

To visit the cities in the order in which they were added to the `Map`, you can do the following:

1) Change the declaration of `mp` from `HashMap` to `LinkedHashMap`:

```
Map<String,Integer> mp = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

2) Iterate over the keyset of the `Map`:

```
visiterator = mp.keySet().iterator();
```

## If you want to specify the order with a Comparator

1) Change the declaration of `mp` to `TreeMap`, supplying a Comparator:

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

2) Iterate over the keyset of the `Map` as in the above example.

## All the code

```
public static void tripsInConfigurableOrder() {
    Map<String, Integer> mp = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    mp.put("Delhi", 1);
    mp.put("Bombay", 1);
    mp.put("Bangalore", 1);

    int numberOfTrips = 5;
    List<String> orderOfVisits = Arrays.asList("Delhi", "Bombay", "Bangalore");
    Iterator<String> visiterator = orderOfVisits.iterator();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTrips; i++) {
        if (!visiterator.hasNext()) {
            visiterator = orderOfVisits.iterator();
        }

        String key = visiterator.next();
        mp.put(key, mp.get(key) + 1);
    }

    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : mp.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key:" + entry.getKey() + ", Value:" + entry.getValue());
    }
}

public static void tripsInNaturalOrder() {
    Map<String, Integer> mp = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    mp.put("Delhi", 1);
    mp.put("Bombay", 1);
    mp.put("Bangalore", 1);

    int numberOfTrips = 5;
    Iterator<String> visiterator = mp.keySet().iterator();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTrips; i++) {
        if (!visiterator.hasNext()) {
            visiterator = mp.keySet().iterator();
        }

        String key = visiterator.next();
        mp.put(key, mp.get(key) + 1);
    }

    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : mp.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key:" + entry.getKey() + ", Value:" + entry.getValue());
    }
}

public static void usingComparator() {
    Map<String, Integer> mp = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.naturalOrder());

    mp.put("Delhi", 1);
    mp.put("Bombay", 1);
    mp.put("Bangalore", 1);

    int numberOfTrips = 5;
    Iterator<String> visiterator = mp.keySet().iterator();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTrips; i++) {
        if (!visiterator.hasNext()) {
            visiterator = mp.keySet().iterator();
        }

        String key = visiterator.next();
        mp.put(key, mp.get(key) + 1);
    }

    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : mp.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key:" + entry.getKey() + ", Value:" + entry.getValue());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    tripsInConfigurableOrder();
    tripsInNaturalOrder();
    usingComparator();
}
```

Comment: thanks for showing the way is there a way we could achieve this without having to use the List ?

Comment: Added a couple alternatives

Comment: customized the data structure to my requirement using doubly linked list appreciate your help in this forum ..

Comment: my requirement was circular linked linked list of Dictionary(map) like elements which would increase the value after every visit to the element and I wanted to know if there was a possibility using maps i could achieve my requirement without having to use customized data structure, the question was wrongly understood by many forum members thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String,Integer> mp = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

mp.put("Delhi",1);
mp.put("Bombay",1);
mp.put("Bangalore",1);

for (int i = 0 ; i < numberOfCycles; i++){
    for (String key : mp.keySet()){
        mp.put(key,mp.get(key)+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: definitely not what i am looking for thanks please read the question again before jumping the gun

Comment: @snoopy You've said this on several different answers. Would you care to explain *why* this does not answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

How about using the while loop and put iteration inside a while loop like this?

```
Map<String, Integer> map = ...
while (true or some condition)
{
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet())
    {
        map.put(key, map.get(key) + 1);
    }

    if (some condition met)
        some condition = false
}
```

EDIT

I read your edited post and here is a solution to what you want to do.
You could use `break` to get out of the for loop when you reached maxCycle.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = ...
int numberOfCycles = 0;
int maxCycle = 10;
while (numberOfCycles < maxCycle)
{
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet())
    {
        if (++numberOfCycles < maxCycle)
            map.put(key, map.get(key) + 1);
        else
            break;
    }
}
```

Say you start from 0 and maxCycle is 5. If you have iterated 5 times, it will go to else and call `break`. After `break` you will go back to while loop and the exit condition is satisfied.

Comment: Please have a look at the added part. That I think would solve your problem.